# when i use httpclient access https web for digest auth and ingore ssl auth, but the ssl error?

Tags: java, https, digest-authentication

```
public class ttttt {    

public static SSLContext createIgnoreVerifySSL() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {  
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");  

    // 实现一个X509TrustManager接口，用于绕过验证，不用修改里面的方法  
    X509TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager() {  
        @Override  
        public void checkClientTrusted(  
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] paramArrayOfX509Certificate,  
                String paramString) throws CertificateException {  
        }  

        @Override  
        public void checkServerTrusted(  
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] paramArrayOfX509Certificate,  
                String paramString) throws CertificateException {  
        }  

        @Override  
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {  
            return null;  
        }  
    };  

    sc.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trustManager }, null);  
    return sc;  
}

public static <NameValuePair, ConnectionSocketFactory> void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String body = "";

    //采用绕过验证的方式处理https请求  
    SSLContext sslcontext = createIgnoreVerifySSL();  

    //设置协议http和https对应的处理socket链接工厂的对象  
    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()  
        .register("http", (ConnectionSocketFactory) PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)  
        .register("https", (ConnectionSocketFactory) new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext))  
        .build();  
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager((Registry<org.apache.http.conn.socket.ConnectionSocketFactory>) socketFactoryRegistry);  
    HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connManager); 


    HttpHost target = new HttpHost("192.168.93.46", 8443, "https");

    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, -1, null), new UsernamePasswordCredentials("cdrapi", "cdrapi123"));

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URI.create("/cdrapi?format=xml"));
             List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add((NameValuePair) new BasicNameValuePair("domain", "username"));
    post.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity((List<? extends org.apache.http.NameValuePair>) nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

    BasicCredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
             new UsernamePasswordCredentials("cdrapi", "cdrapi123"));

    BasicAuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
    DigestScheme digestAuth = new DigestScheme();
    digestAuth.overrideParamter("algorithm", "MD5");
    digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", "passwd");
    digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", "5b3edf3c:cd95b19ed02ecab20f7a9aa24c3373df");
    //digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", Long.toString(new Random().nextLong(), 36));
    digestAuth.overrideParamter("qop", "auth");
    digestAuth.overrideParamter("nc", "0");
    digestAuth.overrideParamter("cnonce", DigestScheme.createCnonce());

    Header auth = digestAuth.authenticate(new
          UsernamePasswordCredentials("cdrapi", "cdrapi123"), post);
    System.out.println(auth.getName());
    System.out.println(auth.getValue());
    post.setHeader(auth);

    authCache.put(target, digestAuth);
    context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
    context.setAuthCache(authCache);

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/cdrapi?format=xml");

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(target, httpget, context);


  }

}
```

Authorization
Digest username="cdrapi", realm="passwd", nonce="5b3edf3c:cd95b19ed02ecab20f7a9aa24c3373df", uri="/cdrapi?format=xml", response="8a5889daee18112d7849e5b77ab015b6", qop=auth, nc=00000001, cnonce="215922d8ee580938", algorithm=MD5

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)

Answer (score 0):

This line has no effect because you ignore the builder it creates for you:

```
HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connManager);
```

You then create your client like this which doesn't know anything about your custom connection manager.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

Solution:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = 
    HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connManager)
                        .build();
```